# Adaptive Cards Input.Date min max value reference

Tags: adaptive-cards

I have adaptive card with two input.date fields - fromDate and toDate. How can I set minimum value for the "toDate" field as a reference from "fromDate" field. so toDate must be always in the future from "fromDate".

I tried

```
 "type": "Input.Date",
 "label": "To",
 "id": "toDate",
 "isRequired": true,
 "errorMessage": "Please enter date",
 "min": "{{fromDate.value}}"
```

but it doesn't work. Is it even possible?

Thanks